# How can I set video memory to max when using vc4-kms-v3d?

Tags: pi-3, video, archlinux, memory

According to Anholt, the creator of the opensource kernel device tree overlay at Broadcom, the maximum is **256M**.

How do I set this? `gpu_mem=256` in /boot/config.txt is not the correct why I think.

There is perhaps false info circling around:

- this option is only valid for modules
- this option is only used by the closed-sourced driver
- not used by vc4
- strategy is to make it smaller to free up memory because vc4 doesn't use it anyway
- some people turn it up when using vc4

Furthermore, there is a way to set memory using the Contiguous Memory Allocator (cma).

What is the proper way to do this? I am looking for some clarification here.

Comment: `gpu_mem=256` is "correct", although I would recommend you use `raspi-config` to change settings. As to whether is is sensible or necessary??